# Image got rotated after reducing the size of bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap

My application takes photo and then uploads it. Since taken photo will be of large size, I have to reduce its size and then upload it. So, I used the following code to reduce the size of image taken by camera which is stored somewhere in sd card. But I dont know what is wrong with the code, the image gets rotated anticlockwise 90 degree if it is portrait else the image is fine when taken in landscape mode.

Following is the code that I used to reduce the size.

```
public File getReducedImage(File mediaFile){        

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(mediaFile);
    return getfileFromBitmap(b, mediaFile.getPath());
}
private File getfileFromBitmap(Bitmap b, String path) {     
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());          
        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();
        Log.v(TAG, "returned");
        return f;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception caught");
        return null;
    }
    //write the bytes in file
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
     final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE=400;
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);

        fis.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / 
               (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "error in bitmap conversion");
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
    return b;
}
```

Edit:
Actually the problem was that the image lost its orientation information once it was resized. I solved it by rotating appropriately. Following is my solution. Hope it will help someone.

public File getReducedImage(File mediaFile) {

```
    Bitmap b = decodeFileWithRotationIfNecessary(mediaFile);
    File f = getfileFromBitmap(b, mediaFile.getPath());     
    return f;
}


private File getfileFromBitmap(Bitmap b, String path) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);


    // you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();
        return f;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception caught");
        return null;
    }
    // write the bytes in file
}



private Bitmap decodeFileWithRotationIfNecessary(File f) {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 400;
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);

        fis.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "error in bitmap conversion");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
            b.getHeight(), getMatrix(f), true);

    return bMapRotate;
}

private Matrix getMatrix(File f) {
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(90);
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            Log.v(TAG, "flip horizontal");


            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:

            Log.v(TAG, "flip vertical");
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 180");
            mat.postRotate(90);

            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 90");

            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            Log.v(TAG, "rotate 270");
            mat.postRotate(180);

            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            Log.v(TAG, "transpose");

            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:   
            Log.v(TAG, "undefined");

            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            Log.v(TAG, "normal");
            mat.postRotate(270);

            break;
        default:
            Log.v(TAG, "default");
        //  mat.postRotate(0);

            break;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "error in finding exif information");
    }

    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One cause may be that you didn't preserve the EXIF data :

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(<file-path>);

int o = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                           ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

//--decode -- encode save--

ExifInterface ei2 = new ExifInterface(<new-file-path>);

ei2.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,o);

ei2.saveAttributes();
```

Default camera app will save with correct orientation applied. If you use your own code for taking/modifying picture, you must save image with correct orientation.

Comment: @Dipendra mostly you would just update orientation tag and most smart image viewers will automatically show image pre-rotated but you can never be sure, so yes, you can actually rotate all the pixels as you did.